# Adding duplicate values in wpdb->prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi can I add a duplicate value in $wpdb->prepare.

I have the following SQL

```
"SELECT
 id,
 MATCH (content) AGAINST('$search')
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(post_search) AGAINST('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

to this

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT
 id,
 MATCH (content) AGAINST(%s)
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(post_search) AGAINST(%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $search_terms)
```

Is there a way of doing this without doing this

```
$search_terms1 = $search_terms;
$search_terms2 = $search_terms;


$wpdb->prepare("SELECT
 id,
 MATCH (content) AGAINST(%s)
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(post_search) AGAINST(%s IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $search_terms1, $search_terms2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of doing this without doing this (... duplicating the variable passed)

Not using `$wpdb`. (Nor with `PDO`, for that matter.) You could stick to passing the initial variable, though, since it's not passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same as in SQL:

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT
 id,
 MATCH (content) AGAINST('$search_terms')
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(post_search) AGAINST('$search_terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
```

Comment: It is using the sprintf format string to help prevent sql injects.

Comment: Ok, then use it with mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: I dont want to get into a debate over escaping strings and wordpress prepare, but I appreciate your help none the less.